# To which part of sentence does "amongst you" refer?

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure

> ...for as much money as it is worth he shall give it me for a
>   possession of a buryingplace **amongst you**. (Genesis 23: 9)

Is the below meaning possible?:

...how much does it cost in your minds? I will pay the cost for it.

Comment: The KJV Bible features hopelessly outdated language. It would be better not to bother with it at all until you've got a firm grasp of *current* English (but if you insist on reading that version, you could easily use any more recent one to see what the text *means*).

Comment: To the closevoter: This question does not ask for the meaning of *amongst you* but for its syntactic role.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No—the price is to be set by Ephron, the owner of the cave of Machpelah. In the AV's translation *amongst you* modifies *buryingplace*—Abraham seeks to bury Sarah *among* the children of Heth.

Comment: Thanks. I ask it because the translator of the persian edition (he was an english man) has translated it as the meaning I wrote above.

Comment: @user64617 Ah ... it's quite possible that your translator was working from the original Hebrew, not from the Authorised Version you cite. In the Hebrew the syntax runs *[for the full price ] [let him sell it to me] [**among you**] [as a burial place]*. English translations more recent than the AV understand *among you* in the sense "in your presence"--that is, the transaction is to be carried out in public to assure that Abraham's perpetual title to the cave is as it were 'registered' in the community's memory.